Excel Run-time error 1004 - PasteSpecial method of Range class failed but code seems to work
I am trying to make an easy way for people to add new rows to a workbook so that they maintain the conditional formatting and merging from the rows above. I have written the following code in the VBA:
Public Sub AddNewRow()
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(1)
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats)
End Sub

I get the 1004 error, but the code seems to work, I still get a new row with the functionality and design of the row above. What can I do to make the error go away, or the code error free?

The first line of your code copies the entire row of the active cell into the row below, including values. Is that what you wanted?

It is a little vague as to exactly what you're trying to achieve, but try this alternative which I think might get you what you want:
Public Sub AddNewRow()
    With ActiveCell.EntireRow
        .Copy
        .Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With
End Sub

Note xlPasteFormats does include merged cells, but does not include the values.
